# Java - hibernate.cfg.xml File Not Found

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, maven

I have my `hibernate.cfg.xml` located at `src/main/resources/` but I keep getting this error when I run my maven project, I have also tried putting the path to the file in the configuration like this but still got the error

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();  
conf.configure("/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

What am I doing wrong?

And when I go to the properties of the project and go to Source I see /src/main/resources in the build path?

It also runs when I make it in eclipse, but when I export to jar it stops working but I have it in class path as you can see[image]

Thanks

**Edit**

Here is my directory in my eclipse project

[image]

And then here is it when I open the .jar file

[image]

Are you saying the .xml should be in the root directory?

Comment: which version of hibernate you are using

Comment: @dom hibernate 4.1.9

Comment: remove string argument from configure and do clean build project and run by defining main class

Answer (score 6):

There is no `/src/main/resources` in your built project, that is just where maven keeps the files before building. While building the project (I assume you are building a `.jar`-artifact) maven will do the following:

1. All `.java`-files in `src/main/java` will be compiled to .class-files and will be moved to the subdirectory of the `jar` corresponding to their package
2. All files from `src/main/resources` will be copied to the root of the `jar-file`

So this file-structure in your project:

```
src
|
+-main
   |
   +-java
   |   |
   |   +- mypackage
   |          |
   |          +- MyClass.java
   |
   +-resources
         |
         +- hibernate.cfg.xml
```

will end up in your `.jar-file` like this:

```
project.jar
|
+- mypackage
|     |
|     +- MyClass.class
|
+- hibernate.cfg.xml
```

The essential point is: All files from `/src/main/resources` will end up in the classpath of your built project. But since your configuration-file is named `hibernate.cfg.xml` and is located on the classpath you should be OK just doing

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
conf.configure();
```

Note that `configure()` is called wthout an argument, so that means "Look for a file called `hibernate.cfg.xml` on your current classpath". So try removing the argument from your `configure`-call.

Comment: I guess it would be a bit more clear, if you would add an example of a file structure before and after building.

Comment: So you are saying what I am doing should be fine, I thought so too, but its not working could you explain a little more about what you mean iwht the `.war` and stuff

Comment: @Jan thanks for the suggestion, Tried to add it to the answer

Comment: @spenf10 I tried to rework my answer to make it clearer. Note what I say about the arguments to the `configure()`-call

Answer (score 4):

When using [maven](https://maven.apache.org) with [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org), one needs only active the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and hibernate.cfg.xml will go into the right place, such that you can run the file using `java -jar jarfile.jar`. The stanza you need is something like:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.example.jpa.Main</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

To generate the appropriate uberjar, type `mvn package` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Are you saying to put the above xml in my pom.xml? And then do `mvn package` in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I'm saying.

Comment: okay I did that and got `BUILD SUCCESS` and then what do I just export as .jar and run it?

Comment: Don't export as jar and run it, do so from the command line and run it as a jar

Comment: Okay I am trying to run this on my server, so you are saying add the project folder to my server -> cd to that folder -> call `mvn package` -> and then run `java -jar jarfile.jar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85442/discussion-between-spenf10-and-hd1).

Answer (score 3):

First clear one thing that if you are using maven with hibernate so there is no need to define the name of `hibernate.cfg.xml` in calling `configure()`

close your project then re-open it
use below code to generate session factory
you need hibernate 4 or above

```
public class HibernateUtils {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtils.class.getName());

    public static void createSessionFactory() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

        try {
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        } catch (Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }

        logger.debug("Session factory created");
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {

        if (sessionFactory != null)
            getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

use the following main class for testing purpose

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateUtils.createSessionFactory();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();

        // do your  task 

        HibernateUtils.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
configuration.configure("src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Use:

```
configuration.configure("/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep your config file under normal src directory itself, not to put under resources folder

[image: Hibernate config [1]]

And refer the file like this
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");

//Here i considered configuration class (HibernateSessionFactory.java)is there within the same package

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your file in `resources` folder then check this `Right click on project->Properties->Deployment Assembly` and check if your resource file map with Deploy Path or not

[image]

Comment: sorry I don't see `Deployment Assembly`?

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: Which version? please let me know

Comment: I am using version 4.5

Comment: Its a Web dynamic project? If yes which server you are using for deployment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85465/discussion-between-spenf10-and-subodh-joshi).